# batch rename/move/del files inside archives

Tags: search, batch-file, archive

Good afternoon, I missed this function in Total Commander (no plugin exists) and nothing find piece of sw to do following:
when I search inside archives (Menu - Commands - Search - Search inside archives) the results can not be showed in "Feed to listbox". I need this function to batch rename/move/del files (search results) inside archives ..  I will appreciate some idea or script or workaround to fit this function ...

Comment: I cannot follow what you want or what you're missing. Try wording this to make it possible/easier to follow/understand; might want to add a screenshot or two. Reading this question 3 times I have no clue what's being done...

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you are saying.